# Text, pictures and videos appear behind my flexboxes

Tags: html, css

fellow coders!

I'm a beginner and learning HTML and CSS. My issue is that when I try to insert a text, video, or picture, it appears behind the flexboxes. I tried different methods such as overflow: auto, visible, hidden. Some of the text is showing behind the flexboxes or below which is visible.

```css
/* Responsive grid */
.layout {
    padding: 24px;
}

.grid {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    margin: 0 -12px;
}

.grid article {
    margin-bottom: 24px;
}

.grid article > div {
    height: 0;
    padding-top: 56.25%;
    background-color: rgb(103, 103, 199);
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0 12px;
}

.grid-2 article {
    width: 50%;
}

.grid-2-1 article {
    width: 33.333332%;
}

.grid-2-1 article > div {
    padding-top: 100%;
    background-color:darkgoldenrod;
}

.grid-2-1 article:nth-child(2n+1) {
    width: 66.666667%;
}

.grid-2-1 article:nth-child(2n+1) > div {
    padding-top: 50%;
}

.grid-3 article {
    width: 33.33332%;
}

.grid-4 article {
    width: 25%;
}

.grid-3 article > div {
    background-color: rgb(231, 153, 64);
}

.grid-2 article > div {
    background-color: rgb(52, 165, 80);
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .grid-4 article {
        width: 50%;
    }
}
```

```html
<main class="layout">
  <div class="grid grid-4">
    <article><div></div></article>
    <article><div></div></article>
    <article><div></div></article>
    <article><div></div></article>
    <article><div></div></article>
    <article><div></div></article>
    <article><div></div></article>
    <article><div></div></article>
  </div>

  <div class="grid grid-2">
    <article><div></div></article>
    <article><div></div></article>
  </div>

  <div class="grid grid-3">
    <article><div></div></article>
    <article><div></div></article>
    <article><div></div></article>
  </div>

  <div class="grid grid-2-1">
    <article><div></div></article>
    <article><div></div></article>
  </div>
```

Comment: are you trying to insert text/image/video into the <article><div></div></article> ???

Comment: @MehediHasanSiam yes i try insert a text/video/image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add a fixed height in .grid article > div. This is happening because you add padding-top and when you are trying to insert text/image it auto going down to another grid. that's why you can't see image/text/.

```css
/* Responsive grid */
.layout {
    padding: 24px;
}

.grid {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    margin: 0 -12px;
}

.grid article {
    margin-bottom: 24px;
    height: auto;
}

.grid article > div {
    background-color: rgb(103, 103, 199);
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0 12px;
    text-align: center;
    height: 100px;
}

.grid-2 article {
    width: 50%;
}

.grid-2-1 article {
    width: 33.333332%;
}

.grid-2-1 article > div {
    padding-top: 100%;
    background-color:darkgoldenrod;
}

.grid-2-1 article:nth-child(2n+1) {
    width: 66.666667%;
}

.grid-2-1 article:nth-child(2n+1) > div {
    padding-top: 50%;
}

.grid-3 article {
    width: 33.33332%;
}

.grid-4 article {
    width: 25%;
}

.grid-3 article > div {
    background-color: rgb(231, 153, 64);
}

.grid-2 article > div {
    background-color: rgb(52, 165, 80);
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .grid-4 article {
        width: 50%;
    }
}
```

```html
<main class="layout">
  <div class="grid grid-4">
    <article><div><p>Hellow</p></div></article>
    <article><div><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/140x100"></div></article>
    <article><div></div></article>
    <article><div></div></article>
    <article><div></div></article>
    <article><div></div></article>
    <article><div></div></article>
    <article><div></div></article>
  </div>
</main>
```